# Boot another OS e.g. Windows *once* on a dual-boot machine

Tags: windows, boot, grub

I have a dual-boot machine with Windows and Linux on it. It doesn't reside at my hand, instead , it's placed in the datacenter which I have to access remotely. For most of time, I work on Linux. But there is some occasion that I have to use the Windows OS on it. Here is the problem. I hope to do all those following things remotely.

1. Do some *magic* to Grub. Reboot the machine from Linux.
2. Grub boots Windows.
3. Access Windows remotely. Work done. Reboot the machine from Windows.
4. Grub boots Linux.

So I wonder whether I can set the booting target at the next time, for *only once*? Thanks.

Comment: This topic has been moved from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917217/boot-another-os-e-g-windows-once-on-a-dual-boot-machine

Comment: Is Windows 7 already installed?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 and Cent OS 6.3 are installed.

Comment: Time to virtualize.

Answer (score 2):

If you have machines in a datacenter, you really need to have remote console: whether that be a KVM, iLo/DRAC/other OOB management, or remote hands at the datacenter that can be walked through what you need them to do.

That said, I am interested in seeing a technical answer for mangling grub from Windows.

Comment: OK, one of my usual insane ideas: run a minimal linux VM and export the physical disk to it (UNSAFE setup; never ever mount anything read/write in both VM and host system even if you dont intend to write to it!)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the grub-reboot utility to boot into another OS without changing the default.

Answer (score 0):

What file system type is /boot on? if it is ext2 you might be able to use something like this to change the grub settings http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html